# Finding in directories that start with "go" but not directories with names that contain "work" or "play"

Tags: linux, bash

I wrote a script that doesn't really work great and could use some pointers.

```
find /mnt/{bob1, bob2, bob3, john1, john2, john3, tony1, tony2, tony3}*/go* -type f -not -path "*/*work*/*" -not -path "*/*play*/*" \( -iname "*.ado" -o -iname "*.do" -o -iname "*.pl" -o -iname "*.py" -o -iname "*.R" -o -iname "*.include" -o -iname "*.sas" -o -iname "*.dct" \) >> /mnt/home/found_programs.txt
```

Just to make it easier to read:

```
find /mnt/{bob1, bob2, bob3, john1, john2, john3, tony1, tony2, tony3}*/go* 
    -type f 
    -not -path "*/*work*/*" 
    -not -path "*/*play*/*" 
    \(   -iname "*.ado" 
      -o -iname "*.do" 
      -o -iname "*.pl" 
      -o -iname "*.py" 
      -o -iname "*.R" 
      -o -iname "*.include" 
      -o -iname "*.sas" 
      -o -iname "*.dct" \) >> /mnt/home/found_programs.txt
```

I need this to write the names of all files with the extensions above that are listed in any directory that starts with "go", but can't have "work" or "play" in the directory name. Trying to do this for work and I can't quite get it to work.

Actual paths and file names have been changed for reasons

Comment: You should post a complete [mcve].  Sample directories and files structure will help us understand your requirement, and test our proposed solutions.  However, you could do the `find` to list all files, than `grep -v` for results you do not want (work and play).

Comment: `/mnt/{bob1, bob2, bob3` etc will fail if you really used spaces.

Comment: Do you mean `"go"` where you wrote `"pm"`? Do you want to look just in directories whose name starts with "go" or do you also want to look in subdirectories of those?

Comment: I did mean "go" where I put "pm"